# Pronsole utility throws several errors when I push gcode commands to Tronxy x5sa 3D printer from an Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: linux, python

I've recently gotten my Tronxy 3D printer to connect to my linux machine running Ubuntu Server 20.04 via a USB serial connection. I am hoping to use Pronsole, (a utility in the printrun tool suite) to help diagnose some problems with a few custom macros. I'm able to launch the Pronsole environment and use the `connect` command to connect to the printer and I don't receive any problems or errors. However, when I push a gcode command directly to the printer via Pronsole ( `G28` for instance ) I get the following output from the command line.
I'm still not familiar enough with linux errors or Python to read these errors or know what to google to find solutions. I guess I'm really just looking for help with the interpretation.

```
ttyUSB1 22°> G28

SENDING:G28

ttyUSB1 22°> Exception in thread read thread:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/printrun/printcore.py", line 333, in \_readline

line\_bytes = self.\_readline\_nb()

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/printrun/printcore.py", line 329, in \_readline\_nb

return self.printer.readline()

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 595, in read

raise SerialException(

serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in \_bootstrap\_inner

[self.run](https://self.run)()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run

self.\_target(\*self.\_args, \*\*self.\_kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/printrun/printcore.py", line 420, in \_listen

line = self.\_readline()

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/printrun/printcore.py", line 354, in \_readline

if 'Bad file descriptor' in e.args\[1\]:

IndexError: tuple index out of range

Can't write to printer (disconnected ?):

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 621, in write

n = os.write(self.fd, d)

OSError: \[Errno 5\] Input/output error


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/printrun/printcore.py", line 750, in \_send

self.printer.write((command + "\\n").encode('ascii'))

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 655, in write

raise SerialException('write failed: {}'.format(e))

serial.serialutil.SerialException: write failed: \[Errno 5\] Input/output error



Can't write to printer (disconnected ?):

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 621, in write

n = os.write(self.fd, d)

OSError: \[Errno 5\] Input/output error



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/printrun/printcore.py", line 750, in \_send

self.printer.write((command + "\\n").encode('ascii'))

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 655, in write

raise SerialException('write failed: {}'.format(e))

serial.serialutil.SerialException: write failed: \[Errno 5\] Input/output error



Can't write to printer (disconnected ?):

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 621, in write

n = os.write(self.fd, d)

OSError: \[Errno 5\] Input/output error



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/printrun/printcore.py", line 750, in \_send

self.printer.write((command + "\\n").encode('ascii'))

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 655, in write

raise SerialException('write failed: {}'.format(e))

serial.serialutil.SerialException: write failed: \[Errno 5\] Input/output error



Can't write to printer (disconnected ?):

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 621, in write

n = os.write(self.fd, d)

OSError: \[Errno 5\] Input/output error



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/printrun/printcore.py", line 750, in \_send

self.printer.write((command + "\\n").encode('ascii'))

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 655, in write

raise SerialException('write failed: {}'.format(e))

serial.serialutil.SerialException: write failed: \[Errno 5\] Input/output error



Disconnecting after 4 failed writes.
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so it turns out my problem was a hardware issue, not a software issue. Whenever the 3D printer would try to execute a command, a power sag would occur and the USB serial controller would briefly lose connection with the host.